# Applying Gradle configuration on condition

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I would like to apply configuration in Gradle script only when condition met:

```
useRepo = System.getenv()["IGNORE_REPO_CFG"] == null

buildscript {
    useRepo && repositories {  // <== HERE
        maven.url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/release'
    }
}

subprojects {
    configurations {
        all {
            useRepo && resolutionStrategy {  // <== HERE
                cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
                cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because of Groovy/Gradle scope magic I can't pass `useRepo` to `buildscript` and `subprojects.configurations.all` scope.

I read about wrapping in class:

```
class Cfg {
    static final useRepo = System.getenv()["SA_IGNORE_REPO_CFG"] == null
}
```

but on `Cfg.useRepo` I got:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cfg
```

**UPDATE** On:

```
project.ext.useRepo = System.getenv()["SA_IGNORE_REPO_CFG"] == null
buildscript {
    project.ext.useRepo && repositories {
        maven.url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/lognet-release'
    }
}
```

I got:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Cannot get property 'useRepo' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you tried, you should use `project.ext`:

```
project.ext.useRepo = System.getenv()["SA_IGNORE_REPO_CFG"] == null
```

but when you now try to use `project.ext` inside `subprojects` it is empty, because it is not defined in this project. so you need to access it with ``rootProject.ext`, cause you defined it there

```
subprojects {
    configurations {
        all {
            rootProject.ext.useRepo && resolutionStrategy {  // <== HERE
                cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
                cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your try the use the `ext` inside the `buildscript`, but that doesn't work, because the `buildscript`-closure gets executed first, and then the other script. See [this Gradle Discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-access-project-ext-variables-from-within-buildscript-section/5706)

If you want to do this all, you can specify this variable on the `gradle.ext` inside the `settings.gradle`.

```
gradle.ext.useRepo = System.getenv()["SA_IGNORE_REPO_CFG"] == null
```

and then use it.

```
buildscript {
    gradle.ext.useRepo && repositories {
        maven.url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/lognet-release'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. With `gradle.ext.useRepo` inside `settings.gradle` I archeived my goal. Can you say why `class` defined in `build.gradle` can't be accessed inside `buildscript`? It looks like Gradle do some magic with classloaders for `buildscript` closure argument...

Comment: @gavenkoa cause the buildscript get executed first before the other build.gradle because you could use classes which are added to the classpath in the buildscript